# Tortoise SVN Server Rebuild

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I believe I have the terms correct, but please let me know if I am misusing them in any way.

I had built a VisualSVN repository on my Desktop a while back, and I had a working copy on my Desktop as well as my Laptop, to sync files between the two.  I rebuilt my Desktop recently and did not backup the repository folder, just the working copy folder.

What is the best way to rebuild the repository, so I can begin sync'ing files again?  Is it just to create a new folder and Checkout the new repo, then export the old files in to the new folder, and perform a SVN Update?  I would like access to the previous file versions if possible, but if not, that is fine as well.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike git, svn is centralised repository which means all revision information are kept on server side, in your case - the repository folder you didn't backup. If you are lucky you may have some cached log from your working folder, this might work differently depends on what is your working folder format, however retrieving those revisions to replicate then in your new repository would be very difficult, but I suggest at least take a screen shot of the cached log for reference.

About building new one, yes you are right, create new repo, checkout the empty folder, export from your old working folder and then commit, update won't be necessary given it's new repository and you alright committed, you would need to perform new clean checkout from other machine.

My suggestion is, keep your repo somewhere else, there should be some providers there provide free hosting if your code base is not too big. If you worry about the hosting reliability, switch to using git, with git you can replicate everything from a local working folder backup, as it's decentralised.